# How to validate doctor registration number in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, validation

[image]

So, Above image has registration number which contains generally letters & Digits and it has max 8-10 length. how to validate it in flutter ?

Comment: always start with "G-"? if not, it is only one letter? and what is the digits length?

Comment: No, That is not fix. You can see that in image. I have updated my question.

Comment: @VrustiPatel I don't see any pattern to match with regex, One possible solution is to loop through the list.

Comment: When do you want to validate it? This does not seem to be an interactive control. It doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

```
String validateRegistrationNumber(String value) {
  RegExp regex =
      RegExp(r'(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])');
  if (value.isEmpty) {
    return 'Please enter registration number';
  } else {
    if (!regex.hasMatch(value)) {
      return 'Enter valid registration number';
    } else {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

validateRegistrationNumber checks that string should contains atleast one letter and digit. until I get proper solution.

call it like this,

```
if (validateRegistrationNumber(controller.registrationNumTxt.value.text)
            .isNotEmpty) {
          snackBar(
              context,
              validateRegistrationNumber(
                  controller.registrationNumTxt.value.text));
          return;
        }
```